# Current version of `mitmproxy` for 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, proxy

I need to tap into some https traffic for development purpose. I use `charles` and `mitmproxy` for that, the later being much more convenient.

I do have some issues though, there appears to be a problem with the buidin web UI in the version of `mitmproxy` offered for systems based on Ubuntu-14.04. I have to manually install the mitm-certificate which is a pain for many devices and changing certificates. So I would like to upgrade from version 0.92 to some current version like 0.15 or 0.17. However all packages I can find of those current versions are only available for newer Ubuntu versions. I don't really understand Ubuntu very well, I mostly work with the openSUSE distribution with its unbelievable wealth of good packages in the OBS. So I am kind of frustrated with the situation for my Ubuntu based systems.

Does anyone have a hint how to get a current version of `mitmproxy` installed on an Ubuntu-14.04 based system?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there really is no packaged version of `mitmproxy` available for Ubuntu-14.04 in a more or less current version.

I managed to install it manually following the documentation on [github](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/README.rst#hacking). It was a bit of a pain, since I had to install and setup lots of python stuff. but finally I managed to get a `mitmproxy` running in version `0.18`. As expected it did *not* show the same issues as that really old version which is packaged for Ubuntu-14.04 (version `0.9.2`).

I only post this to not let this question unanswered, though this does not answer the original question for a less outdated package of `mitmproxy`.